# Firebase storage bucket grants access to some countries only but not others

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase Storage bucket located in **australia-southeast1**. When a user creates an image with my app, that's where the file goes.
Then the image is supposed to be shareable through a download link obtained with the getDownloadUrl() function (so a valid public link with token is generated).

However, when I share that link, people from Australia, Asia and US could access it. But users from EU, Canada, North Africa, etc. couldn't. See an example [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/panoroll.appspot.com/o/users%2FwUAAvEv666PpXEemyrLYhAzlYom1%2FNaturalXManmadeLights.jpg?alt=media&token=c0f75d06-13f8-45a7-8f15-11c6066cac3d).

My guess is that this is because of my bucket's default location. But, I am puzzled since the documentation does not mention any geographic restrictions of this kind and I have not set any specific limitation. It is not even a matter of speed of access, it is just simple access.

Shall I create multiple buckets in multiple locations and duplicate all the images in all buckets to ensure access independently of the user's location?

**Edit: Details of debugging attempts**

- Those who can't access only see a white screen.
- I tried to replicate the issue using VPNs of those countries, and checking the inspector, the console says nothing and for the network part, the GET request gives a '200 Connection established' status but 0 Byte transferred.
- Then I went on and tried to do the GET request from within my app to
  display the image in it. This time, I got in the console a
  '*Cross-Origin Request Blocked...(Reason: CORS header
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)*' message and still the same
  status in the network tab. The app is able to successfully open the
  image on VPNs of locations that can view it.
- Also, I already checked the CORS configuration in Google Cloud and they look fine and allow
  my app's domain to access to the bucket. I even tried to allow any
  domain (by setting the origin parameter of the CORS to "*"), just to
  see what will happen, but the behaviour remains the same (I don't see
  why it would work for some and not for others anyway).

Comment: What are the users in the regions EU, Canada, North Africa, etc getting when they are visiting the link generated by `getDownloadUrl()` method? Are they getting any error response? If yes, please mention the error response.

Comment: Just edited the message to add more details about the debugging.

Comment: How are you checking access for different locations? I checked with [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org) and the test was successful for EU regions with the url you have provided.

Comment: This is getting even weirder then. I tried again with the VPNs and now it seems to work indeed... Back then I tried with [geokeeper](https://geopeeker.com/) and it was failing on EU and South America. Now it seems fine. 

Before posting the issue, I published my app on Facebook last week and had tons of failure feedback from users from those countries... I suspect the issue has been fixed in beetween. But it would be helpful to understand what was the issue. Because meanwhile I had to move all my users' data to a new bucket. This all does not feel very reliable.

Comment: Just retried with Webpagetest (Paris - Chrome and Amsterdam - Firefox). It fails again (white pages and no data transfered). Feels like someone is debugging hard in the background... Hope we will have a clear feedback on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually not an expected behaviour. One reason for this may be the CORS configuration is not properly set. As an initial troubleshooting step I would recommend you to configure it as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration) and in a more detailed manner in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin).

If the above doesn’t help then you may require to raise a support ticket with Google Cloud Platform Support to investigate the issue in detail and find a root cause. If you don’t have a valid support package you may raise a Free [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) ticket.